# Creating unique rows from number of bets 1 X 2 on 8 games

Tags: matrix, arraylist, merge, rows

I have been trying to get rows from a 3x8 matrix (5651 unique rows).
I couldn't make it so now I'm trying to create the rows instead.

Lets say I have a total of 10 bets/game and that the distribution of games look like this:

```
1. 11111111 |XX          |0             
2. 111111   |X           |222           
3. 11       |XXXXXXXX    |0         
4. 1111     |XXX         |222   
5. 11       |XX          |222222        
6. 1111     |XXX         |222       
7. 0        |XXX         |2222222   
8. 0        |XXX         |2222222
```

Every game in the code is an object that has 1,X,2 integers holding the number of each sign.

```
1. 8        2        0
2. 6        1        3
3. 2        8        0
4. 4        3        3
5. 2        2        6
6. 4        3        3
7. 0        3        7      
8. 0        3        7
```

If I for example put the variables together to 8 Arraylists like this:

```
ArrayListGame1: 11111111XX
ArrayListGame2: 111111X222
ArrayListGame3: 11XXXXXXXX
ArrayListGame4: 1111XXX222
ArrayListGame5: 11XX222222
ArrayListGame6: 1111XXX222
ArrayListGame7: XXX2222222  
ArrayListGame8: XXX2222222
```

How can I get all combinations 1-8 to 1 Arraylist that ends up with 10 unique rows?

The challenge is that I wan't it to work even with a bigger amount of numbers/game.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Java. I tried looping through all 5651 rows and added rows that didn't inlcude a bet that reached the number to add on a bet. 

for (int a=0; a <sizeOfRows ; a++){
   boolean add = true;
   for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
    if (rows.get(a).charAt(b) == '1'&&   bet.get(b).nbrtoAdd1 =(bet.get(b).r1)) {
add = false;
    }else if (rows.get(a).charAt(b) == '2'
      && bet.get(b).nbrtoAddX == (bet.get(b).rX)) {
     add = false;
    }else if (rows.get(a).charAt(b) == '3'
      && bet.get(b).nbrtoAdd2 == (bet.get(b).r2)) {
     add = false;
    }
    

   }
if (add == true){

Comment: Java. I tried looping through all 5651 rows and added rows that didn't inlcude a bet that reached the number to add on a bet. 

When a number was added I increased all counters on the bets included in that row